# What is the correct meaning of this Angular async pipe?

Tags: angular, angular6, javascript-framework, angular-pipe, angular-observable

I am very new to Angular and I have the following doubt about this piece of code.

In a view I have this code:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async" >
  <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
    {{hero.name}}
  </a>
</li>
```

iterating on **heroes$**. This is not an array but it is an **Observable** because it is working on this property of the related component:

```
heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;
```

This is not completly clear to me.

Following my interpretation (please confirm or refute).

- The ***ngFor** can't directly iterate on the **heroes$** because it is an **Observable**.
- This **Observable** emit an array of **Hero** but this is an asyncronous behavior.
- The **async** pipe is something thath subscribe this **Observable** and when it is ready (when emit the array) the ***ngFor** directive can iterate on this array.

In practice in this way I can do this operation directly into the view instead to do it in the component subscribing the Observable.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: The `async` pipe also unsubscribes automatically when the component is destroyed, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write it this way then it is more clear:
`(heroes$ | async) as heroList`